# android -retrofit - how to read array and objects from json

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I've this json string , I want to fetch the array and objects from the json /. 
this is my json string :

```
{
"id":"58",
"p":"4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a",
"name":"0634063306cc06340634063306cc",
"contacts" : [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"test1"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"test2"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"test3"
    },
    {
        "id":"4",
        "name":"test4"
    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "name":"test5"
    }
   ]

}
```

as you can see, it has an id , p and name as object and contacts as array

these are my codes in java:

```
public interface UserLogin {
    @GET("/getLogin3.php")
    Call<Contacts>getItems();
}

public class Contact {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Contact withId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

    public Contact withName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}
```

the contacts class:

```
public class Contacts {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("p")
@Expose
private String p;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("contacts")
@Expose
private List<Contact> contacts = null;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Contacts withId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
}

public String getP() {
    return p;
}

public void setP(String p) {
    this.p = p;
}

public Contacts withP(String p) {
    this.p = p;
    return this;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Contacts withName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

public List<Contact> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}

public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

public Contacts withContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    return this;
    }

}
```

and this is the activity class for reading  :

```
 Call<Contacts>rows=connection.getItems();
    rows.enqueue(new Callback<Contacts>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Contacts> call, Response<Contacts> response) {
            Log.v("this", "id" + response.body().getId());
            Log.v("this", "name" + response.body().getName());

            List<Contact>contacts=response.body().getContacts();
            for (int i=0; i<contacts.size();i++){
                Log.v("this","result "+ contacts.get(i).getId()+ " - "
                + contacts.get(i).getName());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Contacts> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("this",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

this is my connection :

```
public class ApiConnection {
private static String BaseUrl = "http://kharident.com";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

the problem is , when I run the code ,it's not successful and it goes to on Failure method ,the error is :

I've checked the json in a json validator and the json is ok

what is wrong with my code ?

```
 Expected name at line 2 column 1 path $.
```

Comment: `the error is` show the error. You didn't show it.

Comment: is `Expected name at line 2 column 1 path $.` the error?

Comment: you provide two contact class, one is missing for P entry.  Make sure what you are using

Comment: Contact  and Contacts model class both are used single class or use as different class if dirrerent class use than put it into single Contact model and pass that model class i hope its work.

Comment: Please debug your code, put a break point inside `onFailure(..)` and in `onResponse (..)` and share your raw response and raw request with us, Thanks.

Comment: What converter are you using? Post full exception.

Comment: Post retrofit builder code.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes , the error is Expected name at line 2 column 1 path $.

Comment: probably you receive not what you expect to receive. Try logging the JSON that you receive as response

Comment: @Bek i just attached my connection

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani as I sayed it goes to onFailue method

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks for reply , How can I get the received json ?

Comment: for example change the `getItems` method return type to `String`. and log the result.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@Expose` annotation in order to deserialize fields. More details in [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html).

Comment: @johnsmoth Your endpoint (http://kharident.com/getLogin3.php) returns a bad json format. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not returning the expected json. It's missing some fields. Your server response is

```
{ 
  ,"contacts":
  [ 
    {"id" : "1" ,"name":"test1"}, 
    {"id" : "2" ,"name":"test2"}, 
    {"id" : "3" ,"name":"test3"}, 
    {"id" : "4" ,"name":"test4"}, 
    {"id" : "5" ,"name":"test5"} 
  ] 
}
```

Try to remove `,` before contacts or add missing fields.

Answer (score -1):

Interface class

```
public interface UserLogin {
@GET("/getLogin3.php")
Call<Contacts>getItems();
}
```

object classes

```
public class Contacts {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("p")
private String p;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

@SerializedName("contacts")
private List<Contact> contacts = null;


public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getP() {
return p;
}

public void setP(String p) {
this.p = p;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public List<Contact> getContacts() {
return contacts;
}

public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
this.contacts = contacts;
}



public class Contact {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
}
```

I made small changes on your object classes, still you problem not sorted, please try this way. I am using exactly this way.